# SQL Server database driver for PHP Laravel in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use SQL Server database driver for PHP laravel in WSL Ubuntu

> laravel 5.8
> WSL ubuntu 20.04
> php 7.3

Please help me to install this. Thanks in advance

I am using this command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-sqlsrv
```

and getting the below output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.3-sqlsrv
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-sqlsrv'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-sqlsrv'
```

Comment: this [helps](https://laravel-news.com/install-microsoft-sql-drivers-php-7-docker)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use one of these commands based on wich you need to install php driver on linux:

`sudo pecl install sqlsrv-5.9.0` or `sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.9.0`

The offical page is this one (version 5.9 is the last with php 7.3 support):
 [5.9.0 for PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.9.0)

Check your correct version from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver16#php-version-support).
Install sql server drivers from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16#installing-on-ubuntu) you have to set your required version in the commands, because by default documentation commands has latest version. Finally you have to install ODBC from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Cubuntu17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline#tabpanel_2_ubuntu17-install) and you are good to go. If you are still facing any  other issue then you have to find the solution by yourself

Comment: Drivers has been installed successfully. But my db is not working it is giving me the following error when I visit my site URL: "could not find driver"
as well in console it is giving me the following error: [Mon May 29 15:25:07 2023] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: [Mon May 29 15:25:07 2023] PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlsrv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0


**Please could you help me with this and IDK why people press down arrow or devote my questio **

Comment: Did added the lines in php.ini:
`extension=sqlsrv.so`
`extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so`
Edit according to your environment

Comment: Also did you run both the 2 commands I wrote in the answer?

Comment: Thank you for the reply bro.. after lot of R&D I find this document link and it is fixed now.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver16#php-version-support

Comment: If my answer is not the resolution, please create a new one with the correct solution, so that if someone have the same problem they can solve it.